# Run multiple MySQL server on a single machine

Tags: mysql

Can we run multiple MySQL servers on a single machine?

Thanks.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes, you just need to run them on separate ports and point them at different lib directories for their data.

Here's a good reference: [http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mutiple-servers.html](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/multiple-servers.html)

(If you want to use this for testing, I suggest checking out [MySQL Sandbox](https://github.com/datacharmer/mysql-sandbox) which is now replaced by [dbdeployer](https://github.com/datacharmer/dbdeployer))

Answer (score 11):

There are various methods to run multiple instances of mysql (on different ports) on the same machine. Here I have used the same binary and used a separate configuration file (with separate port, pid, socket and data directory).
We need to create new directories for our datadir and log folder (if used). Also we need to assign proper permissions on those folders:

```
# mkdir /var/lib/mysql2
  # chown -R mysql.mysql /var/lib/mysql2/
  # mkdir /var/log/mysql2
  # chown -R mysql.mysql /var/log/mysql2
```

Next we need a separate configuration file same as a default mysql configuration file. So start by copying the existing one and changing the needed values.

```
 # cp /etc/my.cnf /etc/my2.cnf
```

(or change the path appropriately for your configuration file is in a different place).

Next, we need to edit our new configuration file with different mysql port (default to 3306), the pid and socket than the default ones, and also point the data and log folders to the ones created before.

```
# cd /etc
  # sed -i ‘s/3306/3307/g’ my2.cnf
  # sed -i ‘s/mysqld.sock/mysqld2.sock/g’ my2.cnf
  # sed -i ‘s/mysqld.pid/mysqld2.pid/g’ my2.cnf
  # sed -i ‘s/var\/lib\/mysql/var\/lib\/mysql2/g’ my2.cnf
  # sed -i ‘s/var\/log\/mysql/var\/log\/mysql2/g’ my2.cnf
```

Finally we need to initialize the default dbs:

```
# mysql_install_db –user=mysql –datadir=/var/lib/mysql2/
```

Finally we can start our new mysql instance with:

```
# mysqld_safe – -defaults-file=/etc/my2.cnf &
```

We can connect to our new instance using:

```
# mysql -S /var/run/mysqld/mysqld2.sock
```

or

```
# mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3307
```

and if we no longer need it, stop it with:

```
# mysqladmin -S /var/run/mysqld/mysqld2.sock shutdown
```

Ref Site : https://linuxinpakistan.com/start-multiple-instances-mysql-machine

Comment: Hey! Welcome to S.O. Simply posting a link containing the answer for your question it's not a good practice. You may add a link but you must provide a solution in the answer text.

Comment: @GustavoStraube Sorry for that

Comment: How about copying mysql.sock file? It's usually not permitted, since it's a special file

Comment: @MariCriss the link is gone... have you tried this procedure?

Comment: Hi, I am running Mariadb 10.5.8 under Archlinux.  /etc/my.cnf only says that mysqld should read from files in /etc/my.cnf.d.  In none of files in /etc/my.cnf.d there is no port socket, path to pid file, path to data directory defined.  What can I do?  Also, your link is dead now.

Answer (score 7):

My steps on `Windows 10`:

1. Copy `C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\my.ini` to `C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\my1.ini`
2. Open `my1.ini` and modify:

   - port=3307(under Client and Server Section)
   - datadir=C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Data1
   - report_port=3307
3. Copy `C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Data` to `C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Data1`
4. Run on `cmd` prompt: (With Administrator privileges if necessary)
   `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin>mysqld --install MySQL80-1 --defaults-file="C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\my1.ini"`

If all went well, you will see:
`Service successfully installed.`

5. <kbd>Win+R</kbd>
   Type `services.msc`, find the service name `MySQL80-1`, right-click on it and click `Start`.

If all went well, you will see the `Status` change to `Running`.
If it did not go well, open `xxx.err` file found in `C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Data1` to check why.

If you do not want the *service* anymore:

- Stop it
- Delete it on the `cmd` prompt using `sc delete MySQL80-1` where `MySQL80-1` is your service name.

Comment: This is a great answer. Awesomely detailed.

Answer (score 1):

For Windows, if the version of mysql server is different then using MYSQL Installer download and install the different versions of the MYSQL server.

[image: MYSQL installer window]

Select **Reconfigure** for each MYSQL server and configure the PORT differently. Complete the configuration steps by clicking next until it is finished

[image: Port configuration window]

Answer (score 1):

Yes definitely,
Create multiple configuration files with different ports.
This is the best resource to understand:

Video Tutorial: [MySQL Multiple Instances](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wCpgjPF0F1A&t=500s)

Reference article: [Click here](https://ittutorial.org/install-multiple-mysql-instances-on-a-linux-server-use-a-separate-mysql-configuration-file/)