# Application that always worked well with MySql5xx crashes in MySql8

Tags: vb.net, ado.net, odbc, recursive-query, mysql-5.1

I'm from Brazil and this my first time here.
I've always used MySql5xx in my ERP in VB.NET using ODBC connection. It always worked very well but now I need to use  the **"With Recursive"**  clause in the query and isn't support in mySQL lower then 8.

The problem is that my app simply crashes after some few interactions with MySQL8, using the Odbc Driver, without any other messagem then just
**"A problem caused your program to stop working correctly. Windows will close the program and notify you if a solution is available"**

I've already tried to install mySql8 in Windows10, Srv2012, Srv2016 but the problem is always the same and I'm unabled to use it.

If someone has any tip, any sugestion, will be very welcome.

Above are the mySql8.ODBC connection strings I'm using

**Dim sOdbcAnsi_MySql8_va As String = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 8.0 ANSI Driver};Server=DELLSRV-2016;Port=3308;DataBase=mydb;UID=root;PWD=xxxxx"**

**Dim sOdbcAnsi_MySql8_va As String = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 8.0 Unicode Driver};Server=DELLSRV-2016;Port=3308;DataBase=mydb;UID=root;PWD=xxxxx"**

And here is the CNN.String that works well with mySql5xxx
Dim sOdbc_MySql51_va As String = "DRIVER={MySQL Odbc 5.1 Driver};Server=LocalHost;DataBase=madepratico_va;UID=root;PWD=1q2w3e4r"

Thanks for now

Comment: See [MySQL Connector/ODBC Developer Guide](https://downloads.mysql.com/docs/connector-odbc-en.pdf) page 47 (`5.6 Connecting without a Predefined DSN`). Various MySQL Documentation can be found [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/).  Here are the available [MySQL Connectors](https://www.mysql.com/products/connector/)

Comment: You may consider using NuGet package [MySql.Data](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data/) instead. See [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-installation-binary-nuget.html) for more information. This is the [connection string](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-connections-string.html) and here is the [MySQL Connector/NET Developer Guide](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/)

Comment: [connectionstrings.com](https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/) is also always worth a look, not just for MySQL.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The default port for MySQL is `3306` as well. To check which port MySQL is listening on, one can use PowerShell. See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71199793/10024425).  The first code block contains the command. The command works for MySQL as well.

Comment: Ops. I forgot to explain that I used the 3308 port in MySql8 because the 3306 was busy with the MySql5xx that was working properly.

But anyway, the problem isn't the port.
But thanks anyway.

Comment: @DouglasWilliamTeixeira  NOTHING can be shared between MySQL5xx and MySQL8 in your configuration.  They just end up destroying one another when sharing folders.  IMHO.  If you NEED multiple versions on ONE WINDOWS server, this URL may be of value to you.  https://www.techbrothersit.com/2018/11/how-to-install-multiple-mysql-servers.html

Comment: It wasn't clear in your original post that you are attempting to run both MySQL 5 and MySQL 8 on the same server. Also, after re-reading your post, it's not clear what trouble shooting steps you've taken. Where did you see this message? In the event logs? SO is meant for programming questions, not for issues with installation and configuration of database software - one of the other forums is more appropriate.

Comment: The following may be helpful: [Running Multiple MySQL Instances on One Machine](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/multiple-servers.html#:~:text=It%20is%20possible%20to%20use,versions%20handle%20a%20given%20workload), [Setting Up Multiple Data Directories](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/multiple-data-directories.html), and [Run multiple MySQL server on a single machine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62966796/10024425)

Comment: After receiving the error message, check to see if the MySQL service is still running. One way to check is to open PowerShell and then run the following command: `Get-Service | Where-Object { $_.DisplayName -Match "^mysql*"}`. For database issues, you'll want to look at both the Windows logs and the MySQL database logs for more information.